# Issue with `TransformFeatureLayer` when using `custom_config` in `preprocessing_fn`

Tags: tensorflow, transform, tfx

System information

- Environment: Linux 5.13.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu
- TensorFlow version: 2.8.0
- TFX Version: 1.8.0
- Python version: 3.8.13
- Python dependencies:
  absl-py                         1.0.0
  alembic                         1.7.7
  anyio                           3.5.0
  apache-airflow                  2.2.5
  apache-airflow-providers-ftp    2.1.2
  apache-airflow-providers-http   2.1.2
  apache-airflow-providers-imap   2.2.3
  apache-airflow-providers-sqlite 2.1.3
  apache-beam                     2.39.0
  apispec                         3.3.2
  argcomplete                     2.0.0
  argon2-cffi                     21.3.0
  argon2-cffi-bindings            21.2.0
  asgiref                         3.5.1
  astunparse                      1.6.3
  attrs                           20.3.0
  Babel                           2.9.1
  backcall                        0.2.0
  beautifulsoup4                  4.10.0
  bleach                          4.1.0
  blinker                         1.4
  cachelib                        0.6.0
  cachetools                      4.2.4
  cattrs                          1.10.0
  certifi                         2021.10.8
  cffi                            1.15.0
  charset-normalizer              2.0.12
  click                           7.1.2
  clickclick                      20.10.2
  cloudpickle                     2.0.0
  colorama                        0.4.4
  colorlog                        6.6.0
  commonmark                      0.9.1
  connexion                       2.13.0
  crcmod                          1.7
  croniter                        1.3.4
  cryptography                    36.0.2
  cycler                          0.11.0
  Cython                          0.29.28
  debugpy                         1.6.0
  decorator                       5.1.1
  defusedxml                      0.7.1
  Deprecated                      1.2.13
  dill                            0.3.1.1
  dm-tree                         0.1.6
  dnspython                       2.2.1
  docker                          4.4.4
  docopt                          0.6.2
  docutils                        0.16
  email-validator                 1.1.3
  entrypoints                     0.4
  fastapi                         0.78.0
  fastapi-utils                   0.2.1
  fastavro                        1.4.10
  fasteners                       0.17.3
  fastjsonschema                  2.15.3
  Flask                           1.1.4
  Flask-AppBuilder                3.4.5
  Flask-Babel                     2.0.0
  Flask-Caching                   1.10.1
  Flask-JWT-Extended              3.25.1
  Flask-Login                     0.4.1
  Flask-OpenID                    1.3.0
  Flask-Session                   0.4.0
  Flask-SQLAlchemy                2.5.1
  Flask-WTF                       0.14.3
  flatbuffers                     2.0
  fonttools                       4.31.2
  gast                            0.5.3
  gin-config                      0.5.0
  google-api-core                 1.31.5
  google-api-python-client        1.12.11
  google-apitools                 0.5.31
  google-auth                     1.35.0
  google-auth-httplib2            0.1.0
  google-auth-oauthlib            0.4.6
  google-cloud-aiplatform         1.11.0
  google-cloud-bigquery           2.34.3
  google-cloud-bigquery-storage   2.13.0
  google-cloud-bigtable           1.7.1
  google-cloud-core               1.7.2
  google-cloud-datastore          1.15.4
  google-cloud-dlp                3.6.2
  google-cloud-language           1.3.0
  google-cloud-pubsub             2.11.0
  google-cloud-pubsublite         1.4.1
  google-cloud-recommendations-ai 0.2.0
  google-cloud-spanner            1.19.1
  google-cloud-storage            2.2.1
  google-cloud-videointelligence  1.16.1
  google-cloud-vision             1.0.1
  google-crc32c                   1.3.0
  google-pasta                    0.2.0
  google-resumable-media          2.3.2
  googleapis-common-protos        1.56.0
  graphviz                        0.20
  grpc-google-iam-v1              0.12.3
  grpcio                          1.45.0
  grpcio-gcp                      0.2.2
  grpcio-status                   1.45.0
  gunicorn                        20.1.0
  h11                             0.12.0
  h5py                            3.6.0
  hdfs                            2.7.0
  httpcore                        0.14.7
  httplib2                        0.19.1
  httpx                           0.22.0
  idna                            3.3
  importlib-metadata              4.11.3
  importlib-resources             5.6.0
  inflection                      0.5.1
  ipykernel                       6.12.1
  ipython                         7.32.0
  ipython-genutils                0.2.0
  ipywidgets                      7.7.0
  iso8601                         1.0.2
  itsdangerous                    1.1.0
  jedi                            0.18.1
  Jinja2                          2.11.3
  joblib                          0.14.1
  jsonschema                      3.2.0
  jupyter-client                  7.2.1
  jupyter-core                    4.9.2
  jupyterlab-pygments             0.1.2
  jupyterlab-widgets              1.1.0
  kaggle                          1.5.12
  keras                           2.8.0
  Keras-Preprocessing             1.1.2
  keras-tuner                     1.1.2
  kiwisolver                      1.4.2
  kt-legacy                       1.0.4
  kubernetes                      12.0.1
  lazy-object-proxy               1.7.1
  libclang                        13.0.0
  lockfile                        0.12.2
  Mako                            1.2.0
  Markdown                        3.3.6
  MarkupSafe                      2.0.1
  marshmallow                     3.15.0
  marshmallow-enum                1.5.1
  marshmallow-oneofschema         3.0.1
  marshmallow-sqlalchemy          0.26.1
  matplotlib                      3.5.1
  matplotlib-inline               0.1.3
  mistune                         0.8.4
  ml-metadata                     1.8.0
  ml-pipelines-sdk                1.8.0
  nbclient                        0.5.13
  nbconvert                       6.4.5
  nbformat                        5.3.0
  nest-asyncio                    1.5.5
  notebook                        6.4.10
  numpy                           1.21.5
  oauth2client                    4.1.3
  oauthlib                        3.2.0
  opencv-python-headless          4.5.5.64
  opt-einsum                      3.3.0
  orjson                          3.6.7
  overrides                       6.1.0
  packaging                       20.9
  pandas                          1.4.2
  pandocfilters                   1.5.0
  parso                           0.8.3
  pendulum                        2.1.2
  pexpect                         4.8.0
  pickleshare                     0.7.5
  Pillow                          9.1.0
  pip                             21.2.4
  portalocker                     2.4.0
  portpicker                      1.5.0
  prison                          0.2.1
  prometheus-client               0.13.1
  promise                         2.3
  prompt-toolkit                  3.0.29
  proto-plus                      1.20.3
  protobuf                        3.20.0
  psutil                          5.9.0
  ptyprocess                      0.7.0
  py-cpuinfo                      8.0.0
  pyarrow                         5.0.0
  pyasn1                          0.4.8
  pyasn1-modules                  0.2.8
  pycocotools                     2.0.4
  pycparser                       2.21
  pydantic                        1.9.0
  pydot                           1.4.2
  pyfarmhash                      0.3.2
  Pygments                        2.11.2
  PyJWT                           1.7.1
  pymongo                         3.12.3
  pyparsing                       2.4.7
  pyrsistent                      0.18.1
  python-daemon                   2.3.0
  python-dateutil                 2.8.2
  python-nvd3                     0.15.0
  python-slugify                  4.0.1
  python3-openid                  3.2.0
  pytz                            2022.1
  pytzdata                        2020.1
  PyYAML                          5.4.1
  pyzmq                           22.3.0
  regex                           2022.3.15
  requests                        2.27.1
  requests-oauthlib               1.3.1
  rfc3986                         1.5.0
  rich                            12.2.0
  rsa                             4.8
  sacrebleu                       2.0.0
  scikit-learn                    1.0.2
  scipy                           1.8.0
  Send2Trash                      1.8.0
  sentencepiece                   0.1.96
  seqeval                         1.2.2
  setproctitle                    1.2.3
  setuptools                      58.0.4
  six                             1.16.0
  sniffio                         1.2.0
  soupsieve                       2.3.1
  SQLAlchemy                      1.3.24
  SQLAlchemy-JSONField            1.0.0
  SQLAlchemy-Utils                0.38.2
  starlette                       0.19.1
  swagger-ui-bundle               0.0.9
  tabulate                        0.8.9
  tenacity                        8.0.1
  tensorboard                     2.8.0
  tensorboard-data-server         0.6.1
  tensorboard-plugin-wit          1.8.1
  tensorflow                      2.8.0
  tensorflow-addons               0.16.1
  tensorflow-data-validation      1.8.0
  tensorflow-datasets             4.5.2
  tensorflow-hub                  0.12.0
  tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem    0.24.0
  tensorflow-metadata             1.8.0
  tensorflow-model-analysis       0.39.0
  tensorflow-model-optimization   0.7.2
  tensorflow-serving-api          2.8.0
  tensorflow-text                 2.8.1
  tensorflow-transform            1.8.0
  termcolor                       1.1.0
  terminado                       0.13.3
  testpath                        0.6.0
  text-unidecode                  1.3
  tf-estimator-nightly            2.8.0.dev2021122109
  tf-models-official              2.8.0
  tf-slim                         1.1.0
  tfx                             1.8.0
  tfx-bsl                         1.8.0
  threadpoolctl                   3.1.0
  tornado                         6.1
  tqdm                            4.64.0
  traitlets                       5.1.1
  typeguard                       2.13.3
  typing_extensions               4.1.1
  typing-utils                    0.1.0
  unicodecsv                      0.14.1
  uritemplate                     3.0.1
  urllib3                         1.26.9
  uvicorn                         0.17.6
  wcwidth                         0.2.5
  webencodings                    0.5.1
  websocket-client                1.3.2
  Werkzeug                        1.0.1
  wheel                           0.37.1
  widgetsnbextension              3.6.0
  wrapt                           1.14.0
  WTForms                         2.3.3
  zipp                            3.8.0

Issue description:
I am using `Tranform` component with arg `custom_config`, like this:

```
  transform = tfx.components.Transform(
            module_file=os.path.abspath(self.cfg.transformer_fn),
            examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
            schema=schema_gen.outputs['schema'],
            custom_config=self.hyper_params
        )
```

If i implement `preprocessing_fn` without `custom_config`:

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    config = Configer(
        os.path.join(__ROOT, "configs", "bert.yaml")
    )
    preprocessor = BertPreprocessor(config)
    outputs = preprocessor.run(inputs)

    return outputs
```

It all works fine with downstream components.

But when I then implement `preprocessing_fn` with `custom_config`:

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs, custom_config):
    preprocessor = BertPreprocessor(custom_config)
    outputs = preprocessor.run(inputs)

    return outputs
```

Transform layer is not working when i want to save model for tf serving, with code below:

```
    def _get_serve_tf_strings_fn(self, model, tf_transform_output):

        model.tft_layer = tf_transform_output.transform_features_layer()

        @tf.function(input_signature=[
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string, name='examples')
        ])
        def serve_tf_examples_fn(text):
            reshaped_text = tf.reshape(text, [-1, 1])
            transformed_features = model.tft_layer({"text": reshaped_text})
            outputs = model(transformed_features)

            return {'outputs': outputs}

        return serve_tf_examples_fn
```

`transformed_features` is `{}`, nothing in it.
Is that i can not use a `custom_config` in this way, or there is some other way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, part of the price of using the power of using tfx is that you have to stick to the function signatures.  In this case, looks like you are trying to do some hyperparameter tuning in your preprocessing layers/functions.  I would recommend putting those in the keras preprocessing layers, integrating those into the model, putting keras tuner hyperparameter configurations into the tuner, and driving that through the `Tuner` component.